# Path from Automator does not work in Applescript

Tags: applescript, posix, automator

I hope someone can assist me as this is most likely a very simple issue - but I have looked online now for a day and cannot find the solution:
Using an Applescript in Automator, I have the following variables in Automator:
FolderPath = /Users/alex/16150
FileName = 16150

In Applescript, I do the following:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set FileName to (input as string)
    set FolderPath to (input as string)
    set FolderPath1 to (the POSIX path of FolderPath)

    tell application "Terminal"

        activate

        do script "\\copy (SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT....'')) TO '" & FolderPath1 & "/" & FileName & ".xml'"

    end tell
```

However, in the Terminal window I keep seeing the following path: '16150/16150.xml' which is not correct. I would need '/Users/alex/16150/16150.xml'

What am I missing? Thanks, Alex

Comment: Log input please

Comment: Hi Pat, Thanks for the reply. I am not sure what you mean by Log input - where can I get it in Automator / Applescript? Alex

Comment: As second line in your script write "log input". Then the content of the var input will be logged. Show us that content.

Comment: Pat, Thanks. As I am running this is Automator, I guess the logging is rather limited...I am now testing it just in Applescript and hope to get a log file to you soon. Thanks, Alex

Comment: Check this https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70116/how-can-i-debug-an-automator-workflow&ved=0ahUKEwjQ6anikoPUAhXHthQKHR4kD58QFggtMAQ&usg=AFQjCNGk6wNeispUgxNzxw0viS3grlxwhw&sig2=GQHVw7O1DyAhklWV3Tfflw

Comment: Pat, I got that, of course, in Automator - yet the workflow runs successfully and the log shows all green without further info. The challenge is that I pass the variables FileName = 16150 and FolderPath = /Users/alex/16150 from Automator into the Applescript where the FolderPath seems to get cut to '/16150' whereas I need '/Users/alex/16150'. In Automator, the variables are correctly defined as I can check them. Any idea? Thanks, Alex

Comment: I guess its only 1 parameter arriving. Thats why i wanted you to log them. And if so why not only passing the folder path and receiving the folder name from it? https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/simple-applescript-to-get-folder-names-parent-folder-paths-and-folder-paths.1089834/

Comment: Pat, Thank you. I finally got rid of the Automator part and run this entirely in Applescript. Works a lot better. Thank you for the good reference from above.